# Techniques for writing good python code

Tags: python

What are the **well-known and generally recognized** (not subjective) techniques for writing good python code. Structuring it (in opposite to spaghetti code). Good practices for decomposition and decision to make new function or class and similar practical things. You can post a link where are described and demonstrating them in opposite to poor practices.

thank you

Comment: Open-ended, subjective questions like this don't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: -1 for subjective, but +1 for hilarious spelling of spaghetti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See:  [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

Code like a pythonista http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Answer (score 1):

General sense applies, and follow the style guide:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/